# PyOpenGL Compute Shader Write To Texture

Tags: python, opengl, compute-shader

I'm trying to implement a compute shader version of a raytracer I wrote in python and I was following this tutorial: [learnopengl](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2022/Compute-Shaders/Introduction).

I can't get the compute shader to write to the texture. I don't even know if the compute shader is running at all. What tests can I do to verify that it's properly compiled and running?

The rest of the code for displaying the texture and the texture object itself work as intended, since by uploading an image directly to the texture, I can display it properly.

SETUP:

```
self.compute_shader = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER)
text = open("../shaders/compute.glsl", 'r')
compute_shader_source = text.read()

glShaderSource(self.compute_shader, compute_shader_source)
glCompileShader(self.compute_shader)

self.program_id = glCreateProgram()
glAttachShader(self.program_id, self.compute_shader)
glLinkProgram(self.program_id)

self.texture = 0
glGenTextures(1, self.texture)
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 200, 160, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None)
glBindImageTexture(0, self.texture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA32F)
```

RENDER CALL:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)

glUseProgram(self.program_id)
glDispatchCompute(200, 160, 1)
glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS)
```

COMPUTE SHADER:

```
#version 430 core

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform image2D imgOutput;

void main() {
    vec4 value = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    ivec2 texelCoord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    
    value.x = float(texelCoord.x)/(gl_NumWorkGroups.x);
    value.y = float(texelCoord.y)/(gl_NumWorkGroups.y);
    
    imageStore(imgOutput, texelCoord, value);
}
```

All I see by executing this code is a black screen. As I said, loading an image data during the creation of the texture object results in the image being displayed correctly on the screen, while by leaving the texture empty and running the compute shader to fill it, I only get a black screen.

Also the fact that with the image loaded, the compute shader doesn't write above the previous image, makes me think that it's either not running at all or not writing anything to the texture.

(size of the screen and of the texture is 200x160)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, turns out the program doesn't work if i use glTexImage2D, the correct way is to use glTexStorage2D.

So instead of:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 200, 160, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, None)
```

use:

```
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, 200, 160)
```

I don't really know why on learnopengl they use glTexStorage2D, nor I understand why it works for so many people, but this fixed my code